# Can't run the flutter project

Tags: xcode, macos, flutter

After some update of macos catalina command "flutter run" stopped working.

```
"flutter doctor":
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.14.7-pre.52, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A603, locale en-GB)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode...

Running Xcode build...                                                  

Xcode build done.                                            3.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **




  === BUILD TARGET path_provider OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulato
    r13.2.sdk/usr/include/module.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'AppleTextureEncoder'
    module AppleTextureEncoder [system] [extern_c] {
           ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/inc
    lude/module.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
    module AppleTextureEncoder [system] [extern_c] {
           ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulato
    r13.2.sdk/usr/include/module.modulemap:7:8: error: redefinition of module 'Compression'
    module Compression [system] [extern_c] {
           ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/inc
    lude/module.modulemap:7:8: note: previously defined here
    module Compression [system] [extern_c] {
           ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulato
    r13.2.sdk/usr/include/module.modulemap:13:8: error: redefinition of module 'Darwin'
    module Darwin [system] [extern_c] [no_undeclared_includes] {
           ^
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 errors generated.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
```

................................................
................................................
................................................
...............................................

Comment: You are trying to use the `macOS` **SDK** to build an `iPhone` app? — that's not going to work. It's actually unclear what you're trying to do without seeing the entire output with the errors.

Comment: Do I have to change that somehow?
I can't send the entire output it's 40k of symbols which exceeds the limit. I can put more info but it will be similar to that /Application/Xcode... block